# Messed up security settings and file permissions in Windows 11 C drive

Tags: windows, security, permissions, uac

Yesterday I was fiddling around with advanced security settings as I couldn’t paste anything in my C drive root.. so I right clicked on c drive , properties, advance setting in security section … and changed the owner from trusted installer to my user… I also checked the child inheritance and subcontainers check mark.. it gave me a bunch of errors like failed to enumerate or access denied, but I ignored them and just pressed continue everywhere after 10-15 mins it gave all the rights .. now the problem starts .. no Microsoft app was working .. be it microsoft store or media player or camera anything .. bunch of services like wappx software protection platform running in background.. eventually slowing down my PC.. Now I just want to reset everything back to normal .. I even reinstalled windows from the iso files and ticked keep personal files and apps and settings option but no luck Kindly guide me to fix this havoc situation

I thought changing the owner from trusted installer to myself would be better as it is my computer but it just broke everything

Answer (score 1):

- If you have a **disk image** made previously, restore from that. There are many tools for making a disk image, such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and a myriad of [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). There are many reasons to make images, such as recovery after hardware failure or serious user error.
- If you do *not* yet have a disk image, make one now, and *verify* it, using an external drive. This will help you recover data after the next step.
- If the PC came with OEM rescue disk, try that to restore Windows and the manufacturers apps.
- Finally, if all else fails, do a **full** Windows installation, discarding all user files.
  Then,
- Recover data and installation files from the disk image, then reinatall all your own applications.

Comment: i have a registry backup.. will that help me revive the old settings and permissions ?

Comment: Not likely because of the overall damage level.

Comment: @mr.anonymous - The registry backup you have is not appliciable to the problem you have currently.

Comment: i reinstalled windows 11, with the option keep personal files ticked.. now 60-70 percent of problem is solved ... calc, mspaint, clock, photos app is not working. and i still cant paste anything i c drive

Comment: Again, you need to backup your personal files and then install from scratch. Keeping the data keeps the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Very clearly, given the mess to the Apps folder and so much not working, then at this point you need to back up what you can to  USB Drive and then do a fresh install of Windows.

You tried a Repair Install and that did not work. No surprise here.

The User Profile is damaged, and reinstall is the only practical solution.